# Sending a specific content of the html form

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to make my html form work with PHPmailer, and in general it's fine. I understand how to make variables in mail.php and use form attribute "name" to send the infromation to the recipient from a visitor.
Something like:

```
$name = $_POST['user_name']
$product= $_POST['product_name']
```

But, can I use the input class name to get the data from it, like this?

```
$phone = $_POST['.className']
```

If I select them in PHP by attribute "name", all inputs with the same names are sent. 
There are very many inputs with the same name, and I need to send only the ones, which are clicked by a visitor.
How can I get the desired result?

Comment: Add some JavaScript, ajax code to send a post request to mail.php by assigning the recipient value to the one element that is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can find elements in a form by class name by using java script.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('.classname');
```

This will however return all elements with the class name ".classname".

I would assign an id attribute to the element you want.  Then you can use:

```
document.getElementbyId('name');
```

Once you have gathered the information you want from the various elements on your form use AJAX to send the data to a mail.php page that uses your PHPMailer script to send out your email.

This is basically what Chethan Kulkarni answer stated.

Comment: The important point here is that in JS you are using a DOM selector to find the elements, whereas in PHP you are specifying a named array index, so they are not interchangeable.